# import java.util.Scanner is not valid,since it does not name a type in a package

Tags: java

im getting an error everytime i try to run my hangman code. Using ready to program IDE, if i hit run it just highlights import java.util.Scanner statement and tells me it is not valid.(import java.util.Scanner is not valid,since it does not name a type in a package. that is exactly what it tells me).
 I am new to this so i would appreciate if anyone could correct the code and just post it as a reply :) thanks.

```
package HangmanSummative;
    import  java.lang.System.out;
    import java.util.Scanner;

class Game
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    int LivesLeft;
    String LetterGuessed;
    String wordInput;
    char[] hiddenWord;
    char[] aOfWord;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean isFound;
    int a;

    public Game ()
    {
        this.setLives (10);

        system.out.println (" Player one enter a word:");
        wordInput = input.nextline ();
        aOfWord = wordInput.toCharArray ();
        hiddenWord = new char [aOfWord.length];
        for (int j = 0 ; j < hiddenWord.length ; j++)
            hiddenWord [j] = '*';

        this.output ();

        while (LivesRemaining > 0)
        {
            system.out.println (" Choose a letter: ");
            LetterGuessed = input.nextLine ();

            this.checkForMatch (LetterGuessed);
            if (isFound == true)

                {
                    hiddenWord [a] = LetterGuessed.charAt (0);

                }
            else
            {
                system.out.println(" Not found.");
                this.reduceLives();

             }
             this.output();


          }
   }

public void setLives (int a)
{
    this.LivesRemaining = a;
}

public void reduceLives()
{
    LivesRemaining = LivesRemaining -1;
    system.out.println("Lives left:" + this.getLives());

}

public int getLives()
{
    return LivesRemaining;
}

public void output ()
{
    system.out.println("Lives left" + this.getLives ());
    system.out.println("Progress so far ");

    for (int i = 0; i <hiddenWord.length; i++)
    {
        system.out.print(hiddenWord[i] + "\n");
    }

}

public void checkForMatch(String l)
{

    for(int i=0; i< aOfWord.length; i++)
        { 
            if(l.charAt(0) == aOfWord[i])
            {   
                isFound=true;
                a = i;
                break;
             }
             else
             {  
                isFound = false;
             }
         }
   }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you think `import  java.lang.System.out;` does?

Comment: The previous line is the problem. Use a real IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of compilation errors in your program. First you can't declare methods or constructors in other methods. Your `main` method seems to contain a `Game` constructor. That is not syntactically correct. Second, gGet rid of this line

```
import java.lang.System.out;
```

It's is not correct because `out` is a `static` member. Remember that the `java.lang` package is always imported implicitly. You could technically do

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

if you wanted to do

```
out.println("whatever");
```

directly instead of

```
System.out.println("whatever");
```

but you aren't doing that so the `import` is unnecessary.

Third, it's `System`, not `system`.

Fourth, its `Scanner#nextLine()`, not `Scanner#nextline()` as you have here

```
wordInput = input.nextline();
```

Finally, there's no instance variable called `LivesRemaining` declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `System.out.println` everywhere instead of `system.out.println`. s should be *Uppercase*.When you are doing `import static System.out` , you can directly use `out.println` to print statements in your code. That's the real usage of *static import statements* in your code. Using static imports should be mostly *avoided* because it creates confusion to the reader. Try to always use `System.out.print` in your code wherever needed.